# Javascript variable reset after leaving if statement?

Tags: javascript

I'm brand new to javascript with a C# background, so I was intrigued when I stumbled onto the following situation:

EDIT: I've included the original text reproducing the issue. The alert text is showing as "undefined". Am I correctly querying the radios?

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            10 <input type="radio" name="group1" value="10"></br>
            20 <input type="radio" name="group1" value="20"></br>
            30 <input type="radio" name="group1" value="30"></br>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="buttonPressed()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**scripts.js**

```
function buttonPressed()
{

var radios = document.getElementsByName("group1");
var checkedRadio;

for(var i in radios)
{
    if(radios[i].checked)
    {
        checkedRadio = i;
    }
}

var tipAmount;

if(checkedRadio == 0)
{
    tipAmount = 10;
}
if else(checkedRadio == 1)
{
    tipAmount = 20;
}
if else(checkedRadio == 2)
{
    tipAmount = 30;
}

alert(tipAmount);
}
```

Why is alertText undefined?

Thanks

Comment: `alertText` shouldn't be empty. Can you give more code for context, such as the actual function call?

Comment: Paraphrasing the code is fine, just make sure that the code actually exhibits the problem before posting it. Here's a working example of what you posted: http://jsfiddle.net/eFRY6/

Comment: Are you saying that the line `alert(alertText);` doesn't popup 10 or 20?

Comment: Calling `var alertText;` at the top of the function defines its scope to the function, and JavaScript doesn't have block scope inside `{}`

Comment: the code does work here, so you are doing something else wrong. http://jsbin.com/acayas

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has no block scope, only function scope. So the code you gave us will work.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work, I suggest you to download `Firebug` so you will have access to the script and put a break point at the first line and press `F10` to debug on every lines and you should find the error quickly or tell us what it does.

Can you try with a loop like this

```
for( i = 0; i < radios.length; i++ ) 
{
    if(radios[i].checked)
    {
       checkedRadio = i;
    }

}
```

Also you could use the value in your checkbox instead of hard coding the tip.

Do you have jquery?

You could do something easy like this

```
$('.group1:checked').each(function() {
tip = this.val();
});
```

Comment: I suggest you download the nicest browser Chrome and uses the Chrome Developer Tools

Comment: Yeah, but Chrome has some pretty awesome developer tools right out of the box.  No need to download plugins and have to worry about that big ugly mess.  (Is FF still releasing an update every 12.1234142 seconds that renders all your plugins "out of date"?)

Comment: well I use both of them and firebug for a long time and it's always fine after an update of firefox. I like them both